# Chrome Devtools -> Sources -> How to switch the default tab from Page globally?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Recent Chrome updates introduced a feature that adds unnecessary clicks to my workflow. Not a lot, but enough to annoy. Devtools used to save the state you left them in across the chrome instance globally. Now Devtools do it per domain. Which kinda makes sense for the people who do different kinds of development on a few different sites within the same browser instance.

I do a lot of dev on tens of sites and over time I get new sites to work on. But what I prefer to use doesn't really change. In particular, in 85% of cases when I go to Sources, I want my snippets. In 10%, I want Overrides, 3% for Page and 2% for content scripts. So it makes sense for me to have Snippets on by default across all sites and all instances of Chrome.

I thought if I changed the order of the tabs in the Sources, it would select what's first, but no. Pages seem to be hardcoded to be selected by default unless there's a preference for a given domain.

Tried going through the Sources settings, but didn't find anything to address this.

Now, my hopes aren't high, but is there a neat way to change that default logic of what's opened by default in Sources globally for a given Chrome instance?

Comment: It uses the same customized order here regardless of domain. I've used [devtools-on-devtools](/q/12291138) and saw the order of Sources tabs in stored in one shared localStorage for devtools://devtools origin. What you describe may be a bug, e.g. I see devtools no longer re-opens the last opened snippet.